# How to decide the colour combinations while setting up still life objects?

Tags: color, composition, still-life

Let's assume I have bottles of different colours. I want to make a still life photograph with them.

How should I decide which colours go well with others?
Example - should blue bottle be placed next to yellow or to red?

Have any studies been done on this subject? Or any website which explains the colours which when put together look most attractive to human eye?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a still photographer.

However, I think those following links provide really good explanations about what is color theory in general and how to use it :

- A video introducing the color theory : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GP0OyqECAS4 (website : http://theartofphotography.tv/episodes/color-theory/)
- A good article with examples : http://erickimphotography.com/blog/2013/11/26/street-photography-composition-lesson-12-color-theory/

Both links explain what is the *color wheel* and from that take you to *complementary colors*, *analogous colors*,...

With no real experience in still photography, I imagine it to be close to website color design. Once you know how a color wheel works and how to use it, my two favorite websites are :

- https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel/
- http://paletton.com/

If you want a good book, have a look at [http://www.amazon.com/The-Photograph-Composition-Color-Design/dp/1937538060](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1937538060). I got it 2 weeks ago, have only read about 20 pages but it's already a very helpful help... even if it is hard to read at first for non native English speaker. This other one ([http://www.amazon.com/Interaction-Color-Revised-Expanded-Edition/dp/0300115954](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0300115954)) seems to be a classic, but not yet on my bookshelf (maybe I should have bought it first).